# All Possible combinations of data in multiple columns separated by a delimiter

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I was able to perform a Cartesian product on multiple columns which have a single value in every cell. However, I was wondering if there is a way I could transform a Unflattened Data separated by delimiter into a Cartesian product

For example

```
ID         ID2                  String                      String2
123   123;1234;1234    Sample; Sample; Sample           other; other
```

I want all the possible combinations to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, split each of the 4 columns into an array on ";" then nested loop them all:

```
Sub Cartesian()
Dim MyStr1 As Variant, MyStr2 As Variant, MyStr3 As Variant, MyStr4 As Variant, Str1 As Variant, Str2 As Variant, Str3 As Variant, Str4 As Variant, X As Long
MyStr1 = Split(Range("A2").Text, ";")
MyStr2 = Split(Range("B2").Text, ";")
MyStr3 = Split(Range("C2").Text, ";")
MyStr4 = Split(Range("D2").Text, ";")
X = 4
For Each Str1 In MyStr1
    For Each Str2 In MyStr2
        For Each Str3 In MyStr3
            For Each Str4 In MyStr4
                Range("A" & X).Formula = Str1
                Range("B" & X).Formula = Str2
                Range("C" & X).Formula = Str3
                Range("D" & X).Formula = Str4
                X = X + 1
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

I had the data in row 2 and this starts posting to row 4 onwards. You can play around with your ranges as needed.

Comment: It is smart enough to still work, it will just be a single element array :).  I ran it on your sample data and got 18 rows back which is the number I was expecting (1*3*3*2)

Comment: Can we print this beside the original array instead of below? Or just erase the original?

Comment: Sure, change X = 4 to X = 2 (X is the starting row) to overwrite your data, if you want ot to the side you need to change X and also the A, B, C, D in the loops to be the columns you want.

Comment: No probs, happy to help :)

Comment: Can you help me change to work for multiple rows? Instead of only A2-D2? I tried to put a range and loop but unable to get the result @Dan Donoghue

Comment: Where do you want the results to appear? One set after the other in column F down?

Comment: Overriding the existing data @Dan Donoghue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76491/discussion-between-user3317862-and-dan-donoghue).